# Text flowing outside div in IE with angular material

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, flexbox, angular-material

I am having these issues using **angular material** on **IE** (i'm using latest version **edge** and same result for other versions (9,10,11)

1. Text is flowing outside div tag
   [image]

The below is snippet code for the current div containing 'Task' item, **This is the html and css only (the screenshot will demostrate the issue)**.
*(note that multilingual-message is a custom directive for multi-language texts support.)*

```css
.comp-insp-th .th-cell {
  background: #1e9a9f;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="th-cell flex" flex="">
  <multilingual-message message-id="Home.Task" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <span ng-bind-html="message[CurrentSettings.language] | unsafeHtml">Task</span>
  </multilingual-message>
</div>
```

2. **Divs (tags) not taking paddings and margins**, the below is snippet code with styles, using angular material directive  'layout-align' and assigned as "space-between stretch" wich will add space between items in column, still the tags are overlapping and paddings/margins not working even if added manually.

[image]

Comment: please provide a complete and __working__ code snippet that shows the problem when run on IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried angular material Troubleshooting tips but it did not help me that much,
The two issues were the effect of flexbox layout which is not totally supported on IE-11, then after a deep inspection -and with the help of a friend- I figure it out, the solution is adding `-ms-flex: 1 0 30px` to the `.flex` class of the element where 30px indicates the **prefferedHeight** for the flex item, then change the value based on each element height you preffer. 
Note to mention that you should always add a selector before .flex class for your current element, in my example:

```
.comp-insp-th .th-cell .flex{
  -ms-flex:1 0 30px !important;
}
```